# How to decode JavaScriptSerializer object in php

Tags: php, asp.net, json, email, serialization

My goal is to send request from **asp.net's** page to **php's page**, and send email from php page.
my code on **asp.net's** page is

```
            Dictionary<string, string> keyValues = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            keyValues.Add("to", "to@gmail.com");
            keyValues.Add("from", "from@gmail.com");
            keyValues.Add("message", "Conent of Email");
            keyValues.Add("Subject", "Subject of Email");
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            string json = js.Serialize(keyValues);

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
            formData.Add("a", json);

            byte[] response = webClient.UploadValues("http://example.com/emailme.php", "POST", formData);
            string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
```

the value which i'm passing after Serializing is

[image: Json string which i'm passing to]

and the code written in my **php** page is

```
if (isset($_POST['a']))
{
echo "Value Exists"; 
echo "<br> Value before decoding is ".$_POST['a']."<br>";

$result=json_decode($_POST['a'],true);

echo "the value after decoding is ";
echo $result;

echo "<br> now for print_r <br>";
print_r($result);


} else 
{echo "Value Does Not Exists";}
```

it was the code, now i'm attaching the image of result for my request.

[image]

As you can see the it shows the result before decoding for after decoding it shows nothing.
i will proceed for sending email after the result.

Comment: maybe you should stripslashes(); before json_decode();

Comment: $result=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['a']),true); @Aleksandar it worked for me. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result=json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['a']),true);
```

will do the trick ;)